# How would you structure this sentence so that it expresses what I want to express

Tags: sentence

The sentence I first came up with was

> "We can't put people's lives at risk because of the benefit that we
> don't know when it will going to be realized"

Even writing this sentence I felt somewhat awkward with using "it".

So I rewrote the sentence like

> "We can't put people's lives at risk because of the benefit which we
> don't know when will be realized"

But I felt awkward with this sentence as well

I have no idea know how to express what I want to express

I don't know if these sentences are grammatically correct, but I bet most of you get what I want to say

I want to know what can be done to these sentences so that it shows my intention

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry. I didn't know I wasn't allowed to post this question Sorry for all the inconvenience I caused and thanks for all the help. I appreciate it!

Comment: Not permitted to edit you here. But two sentences will help. Break after "We can't put people's lives at risk because of the *expected* benefit."

Comment: "We can't put people's lives at risk because of a benefit that is uncertain."

Comment: There are far more problems here than _it_.

Comment: @Greybeard so is it basically impossible to structure the sentence in a way that "benefit" comes first followed with "that~" to describe "benefit" is uncertain to "us"? I mean, I'm perfectly fine with your sentence, but your sentence doesn't imply "we" are the ones who are not certain about it. Just to be more concise, what I want to exress is

Comment: @Greybeard Benefit<----- (We don't know when it is going to be realized) so basically I want to know how to put this together into a sentence. "The benefit that~(We don't know when it is going to be realized)" what can I write in the paranthese so that it's grammatical and shows my point

Comment: We can’t put people’s lives at risk for a perceived benefit which may or may not come at some point in the future.

Comment: I think what you are really looking for is writing advice.  Happy to give it, but technically the right site for that is writing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "the benefit which we don't know when will be realized" is the non-grammatical part.

Comment: @mjjf [writing.se] is for people writing -stories, not for grammar help as a second language learner. The appropriate sites for that are [ell.se] or [languagelearning.se]

Comment: @Mitch I don't consider this as grammar help, they seem to want to express their idea the best way possible.  Yeah, grammar is a part of that, but it is part of all formal writing. Btw, where did they mention English is a second language for them?

Comment: @Mitch I checked the rules of writing.stackexchange.com, appears that I was correct: https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - a little rewriting of the question to include context may be necessary, but it seems to fall under this rule: "Questions asking for help expressing a concept or an idea, within limits. (See this meta post for more information.)"

Comment: @mjjf It is not a good fit for Writing. The associated meta post says: *"Please rewrite this sentence for me": off topic*. (Plus, being the Writing SE mod that edited that Help Center page last, my opinion must count for something.)

Comment: @Laurel I read the meta, and I said with a little context added to the question it would fit.  I was referencing this piece of the meta post: "The distinction between this and the help me express an idea questions may be a little fuzzy, but basically an 'express this idea' question will contain a description of the idea to be expressed. It may or may not contain the authors current idea of how to express that idea."  I really don't see how this falls out of line with that, assuming they provide the needed description/background/context/idea.  Seems nitpicky at that point.

Comment: @mjjf Laurel prebutted your point about "I read the meta" with "I wrote the meta". Neither [writing.se] nor [english.se] are appropriate sites for questions to help rewrite a sentence (especially one where the many grammatical errors of the type made by a language learner.

Comment: @Mitch Just because someone contributed to the meta or is a moderator doesn't make them right ‍♀️ I think I made a good case for why this question could have been posted there with edits.  I stand by it.  You shouldn't assume someone is learning English as a second language based on their grammar.

Comment: I admit it was my mistake. I should have checked the rules prior to posting the question. It's been too long ever since I last used this site. I don't know if it would be best to delete my question. Should I delete it or leave it for other people?

Comment: @user547075 You didn't do anything wrong and in a perfect world the comments you found would have been welcoming, helpful, and directed you in the right way to use the site without condescension. I hope this doesn't turn you away :) Based on what I've read in the Help Center there isn't a way for you to delete it at this point.  It is only one post of many, so it isn't a big deal for it to be left as-is, or you can try editing it to have it re-opened as on-topic.

Comment: Our sister site, English Language Learners, is a friendly place with a lot of helpful information.  I hope you'll give it a try too, and if you do, I hope you'll like it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding my two cents :)  I'm treating this more as writing advice than a grammatical analysis of your original sentence.

> We can't put people's lives at risk because of the benefit which we don't know when will be realized.

If I were trying to write a similar sentiment, I might phrase it in one of the following ways.  Note however that there is no correct answer, and other answers provided to this question may be just as or more suited to your purpose.

- "The possible benefits of this venture aren't worth putting innocent people at risk."
- "When weighing the future benefits against the risks involved, we cannot, in good conscience, continue."
- "We can't put the lives of others at risk for a benefit we may never live to see."

Comment: Downvoting because you really shouldn't write an answer to an off-topic question.

Comment: @aparente001 it was marked as off-topic after the answer was posted - also what is the harm?

Comment: @mjjf The harm comes in when the OP realizes that their post is totally off-topic, but then can no longer self-delete because there are posted answers....it is a feature of the system, and usually requires a cleanup by reviewers...a question like the one above benefits no one apart from the OP, does not help the site in its purpose, and is ill-considered. You are new, but I am sure you will see that in the near future. All of that said, I do not believe that DVing an answer to a dodgy question is the type of thing we should be doing here.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I'm not new, but appreciate the answer.  I didn't realize they can't delete their question when it has answers.  Thanks for being constructive.

Comment: _[dux servit ductis_](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/what-is-the-preferred-translation-of-a-leader-serves-into-latin)

Comment: @mjjf - it was intended as a friendly word to the wise.  It's just not useful to the site, as a compendium of knowledge, to have muddy questions and muddy answers cluttering things up.  Helping people with rewrites isn't part of the mission, as well-intentioned as you clearly are.  And rewriting when the question is off-topic *and* unclear is counter-productive.  Here's one productive thing an enthusiastic participant can do when they have some free time: familiarize themselves with some of the best answers in the archive, which can help them propose duplicates that are a good match.

Comment: @aparente001 I appreciate that point of view, thanks for explaining.  I couldn't help but answer, and honestly I thought I was on ELL when I posted it, so that's my mistake. Even so, may have been a bit harsh to downvote the new contributor's post (not mine, teacup's).  It's hard to post for the first time and be instantly chastised for providing a helpful answer. Advice or pointing to the rules would be more encouraging. I think the SE community usually means well, but there are a lot of posters who are turned off by the lack of welcoming collaboration. I like to think that's not intentional.

Comment: @mjjf - Yes, in retrospect, I regret the teacup downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You’re right, “it” is ambiguous. I’m for being specific and inserting the exact noun/phrase descriptor of the thing that will risk people’s lives and might have benefits. I’ve created a few examples to illustrate, using “riding bikes to work” as a silly placeholder for whatever you’re dealing with. It’s unclear to me if you have any specific benefits in mind, so I’m assuming not.

> Any benefit, if such benefit ever materializes, of riding bikes to work cannot merit risking people’s lives.

> Risking people’s lives to ride bikes to work is not worth the benefits, when any ever occur.

> Implementing a policy to ride bikes to work would be immoral, as such a policy will continually risk our employee’s lives, and any benefit would be future and potential.

Sometimes looking at the structures of surrounding sentences can help demystify the current issue. Maybe something like the following will work as a conclusion sentence if the preceding sentence has the requisite information.

> It would be immoral to risk lives for a potential future benefit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mffj thank you both for the feedback (observed from other comment's thread, no reputation, answering here) I will certainly review meta for guidance before more interactions. If an observation might help with how to deal with uninitiated ignorance, I had no intention of returning to this community after seeing a down vote and seemingly unrelated explanation. why expend the time if it's to be summarily dismissed? I'm glad it was still open in my browser today. I now understand and appreciate the reason and can better my condition with study.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm probably screwing this up too, sorry. I'll get the hang of it. *see previous comment

Comment: @teacup - Please forgive me -- it wasn't fair to downvote your answer too.

Comment: @teacup Glad you stuck around, I've been in the same boat before.  It's a common problem - a lot of veteran SE users (and some that are just following the letter of the rules with no intended malice) use downvotes even on clearly well-written, well-intentioned answers when a comment instead could have been both encouraging and achieve the same (or better) result.  Everything is a nail around here sometimes :)